# Firebase realtime database remove code is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I created an EventListener wherein I will delete a data in the Firebase Realtime Database. Everytime I try it, it always prompt the alert that says "Crop successfully deleted" but never deleted in the Realtime Database.

```
DeleteData1.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  var deleteCrop1 = document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value;

  remove(ref(database, "Crops/" + deleteCrop1.value))
  .then(()=>{
     alert("Crop successfully deleted");
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
     alert("Unsuccessful, error" + error);
  })
});
```

Comment: If you `console.log(deleteCrop1.value)` right before you call `remove`, what does it output? Does that node exist in your database? Can you share a screenshot of that?

Comment: It says undefined, but upon checking my text area has an id that is called deleteCrop.

Here is my database https://prnt.sc/88Qoxjs5VsoJ added a screenshot.

Comment: If it prints `undefined` it doesn't really matter what you have in the database anymore. You're deleting the data at `Crops/undefined`. Since that doesn't exist, it is a noop. --- The problem comes from the fact that you have `.value` twice: once in `var deleteCrop1 = document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value;` and once in `remove(ref(database, "Crops/" + deleteCrop1.value))`.